# How to dynamically hide or show SWT password

Tags: swt

In my login dialog, there is a Button:

```java
Text pwdT = new Text(container, SWT.BORDER|SWT.PASSWORD);
Button plainBtn  = new Button(container,SWT.CHECK);
```

If I select `plainBtn`, I want the password shown in `pwdT` to change to plain text rather than ciphertext? Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `setEchoChar()` method can be used to control whether the entered characters should be shown or not.

To show the actually entered characters, clear the echo char like this:

```java
text.setEchoChar('\0');
```

You can even create the `Text` widget without the `SWT.PASSWORD` style flag and solely change the password character at runtime.

If some of your targeted platforms do not support changing the echo char like macOS, you can re-create the password text field without the `SWT.PASSWORD` style flag. For example:

```java
Text oldText = text;
Composite parent = oldText.getParent();
Control[] tabList = parent.getTabList();
// clone the old password text and dispose of it
text = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER);
text.setText(oldText.getText());
text.setLayoutData(oldText.getLayoutData());
oldText.dispose();
// insert new password text at the right position in the tab order
for(int i = 0; i < tabList.length; i++) {
  if(tabList[i] == oldText) {
    tabList[i] = text;
  }
}
parent.setTabList(tabList);
parent.requestLayout();
```

Comment: Setting the echo character to '\0' with SWT.PASSWORD doesn't work on macOS

Comment: @greg-449 Thank you for pointing this out, I have added a workaround to the answer.

Comment: Thank you! However it is incredible that we have to recreate the field just to change its state.